# Interpret USB joystick axis

Tags: c, linux, usb, joystick, gamepad

There are a fair few questions about this already, but none answered my question.

I have a Saitek P990 Dual Analog Gamepad, and want to read the joystick movements as intelligible data that I can use to control motors etc.

How would I go about doing this? I would like to write some c code to do this job, if it's possible, but I'm quite new to C and so would need pretty clear explanation :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to read the raw joystick you have two basic options:

- Read the old `/dev/js0` (or `/dev/input/js0`) device with joystick events.
- Find the relevant new `/dev/input/event*` device and read generic input events.

You can find examples of both easily on the Internet.
Or you can use the source ([joydev.c](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/input/joydev.c), [input.c](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/input/input.c))!

For quick testing, many distributions have the `input-utils` package. Its source code will be most enlightening.

QUICK LINK:

See for example the tutorial [here](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6429). The basics are:

1. Open the device `/dev/input/event*`, with `open()`.
2. Use the `ioctl()` system call with the `EVIO*` codes to identify the device.
3. Read the events with `read()` into `input_event` structs.
4. Identify the interesting events and use them!

As I said before, it will be most useful to run the `input-events` util from the console, to see the input events as your program will receive them.

Comment: could you point me in the direction of some of those examples? I didn't really understand much of what I found.

Comment: ok, thank you! This is going to be no small task, I feel. I'll try and work out how to do it from what you've given me :)

Comment: @theoB610: YW! Go on! And if you find any difficulty, do not hesitate ask as many questions as needed. But remember that a concrete question -with code, if possible- is more likely to get a concrete answer.